# How to append a querystring to the url created by Url.Action base on a hidden fields values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hidden-field, url.action

Here is my controller Action method

```
public ActionResult ChangeStateId(int userId,int stateId)
 {
   return RedirectToAction("Index")    
 }
```

and in my anchor tag of View, i want to redirect to above action method with parameter values like this

```
<a href="'@Url.Action("ChangeStateId","User")?userId='+$('#hidID').val()+ '&stateId=' +$('#hidStateId'.val()")></a>;
```

but it is not working for me.

Comment: Explain how it's not working, at run-time what is the value of href?

Comment: Your quotes and parenthesis aren't in the right order... There is a bracket after the double quotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `a` Tag:

```
<a id="GoToRedirectAction" data-url="@Url.Action("NewTelegramHlink", "Hlink",null, Request.Url.Scheme)">Go To Redirect Action</a>
```

With these `jQuery` codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#GoToRedirectAction').click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('url') + "?userId=" + $('#hidID').val() + "+&stateId=" + $('#hidStateId').val();;
    });
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on("click",'a#GoToRedirectAction',function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('url') + "?userId=" + $('#hidID').val() + "+&stateId=" + $('#hidStateId').val();;
    });
});
```

Comment: click function is not getting fired with this.

Comment: @Steve. I tested this answer it works well, Check that you referenced jQuery library to your page.

Comment: @Steve. I did not apply any important change to the answer, i just made its codes a few shorter. I have tested it before write it in `stackoverflow` for you and it works well.

Comment: `a` tag is in pop up so may be that why it is not calling the function

Comment: @Steve, i added another way in my answer to set `a` click handler, perhaps it solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you wants to **work in HTML** please try this, I have put static value, you can convert it with dynamic as per your requirement.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ChangeStateId", "Home", new { userId = 1, stateId =2})" )>Click</a>
```

**For Jquery:**

```
<a href="#" data_controller="Home" data_action="ChangeStateId"  id="ancChangeState">Click JQuery</a>

$("#ancChangeState").click(function () {            
        var controllerName = $(this).attr("data_controller");
        var actionName = $(this).attr("data_action");
        var userId = $('#hidID').val();
        var stateId = $('#hidStateId').val();

        if (userId == undefined)
        {
            userId = 1;
        }
        if (stateId == undefined) {
            stateId = 1;
        }        
        var url = "/"+controllerName + "/" + actionName +"?userId="+userId+"&stateId=" +stateId+" ";

        window.location.href = url;
    });
```

Comment: which `a` i need to use?

Comment: I have given you two solution. (1) first a:  in html View (2) second a : Jquery use

Comment: but with first one it is not working while assigning hidden value to my parameters.

Comment: you have to just assign dynamic parameter value instead static one, you can also try second option

Comment: I have posted the answer in simple steps

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML CODE

 <a href="#" onclick="viewAllOrder()" class="back-btn" style="float:right">View All</a>

JAVASCRIPT CODE
     function viewAllOrder() {
            var customerId = $("#ddlCustomer").val();
            var month = $("#ddlMonth").val().toString();
            var monthData = String(month);
            var salesOrg = $("#ddlSalesOrg").val();
            var url = "/Order/Index?CF="+"OD"+"&customerId=" + customerId + "&monthData=" + monthData + "&salesOrg=" + salesOrg;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
```